# Google Cloud Messaging ANDROID, what can I transmit

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm a little confused about what I can practically do with GCM.

Apart sending simple notifications, would it be possibile to configure my app in order to receive information from GCM (periodically) and to save them into a DB?

In other words, not just notification, but real information that will be implemented by the app itself, according to my needs.

Thank

Answer (score 1):

You could do it, but you shouldn't.

It is important that you look correctly at the usage of the GCM pushes - they are **not supposed to transfer data,** but rather **notify the device that something happened or should be done**.

So, if you want to obtain some data, use the GCM to notify your app about it and then from the app make a normal http request to download the data and save it to your DB.

Answer (score 1):

GCM should be used, as it is called, for notifications. You can pass data through GCM, but more strings or simple objects rather than serialized objects or data.

Maybe websockets might be the thing you are looking for !

Comment: Would you advise GCM for a JSON strings? It would be my necessity, and then to save that data to the internal DB of the App

Comment: How do you plan to send your GCM notifications ? What is your server runnin on ? node.js ?

Comment: I would use a server on Digital Ocean: Ubuntu 14.04 and Python 2.7. I still have to build it, it's going to be the first  time I use GCM in my App, that's why I have many doubts.

Comment: I'd say why not. GCM is pretty simple to use by the way...
Maybe the better option is to make your own opinion by trying it !

Answer (score 1):

The GCM push is often used as a tickle, to get your application to execute a fetch against the server.

However, you can encode the message with a payload.

Google App Engine

```
Message message = new Message.Builder().collapseKey(MsgType).addData("payload", Msg).build();
```

Android on Message received

```
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        startcontext = context;
        String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(context); 
        if (regId.equals("")) return; //Get out of here because we are not registered

        String payload = intent.getStringExtra("payload");
        CNMessage msg = new CNMessage();
        msg.fromJSONString(payload);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can send data via GCM as long as it is no bigger than `4KB`

> Set data with your custom key/value pairs to send a data payload to the client app. Data messages can have a maximum 4KB payload.

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages

GCM is meant for only alerting the device that there is new data to get then once that message is received by the device the device goes and gets the data from the server

Comment: BTW: `kb` stands stands for **k**ilo (1000) **b**its and is far lower value than **K**ilo (1024) **B**ytes as you probably wanted to write. It should therefore be `KB` (or `KiB` if we want to stick to `kibi` prefix)